# TypeScript wont allow dynamically evaluating a property on an object/map with a string key

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
const formatters = {
  time(value: string): string {
    const serialized = moment(value, dateTimeFormat, true);
    return serialized.format('MMM Do YYYY HH:mm');
  },

  date(value: string): string {
    const serialized = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
    return serialized.format('MMM Do YYYY');
  },

  stringUpperCase(value: string): string {
    return value.toUpperCase();
  },

  // ...
}
```

Then I want to try and dynamically find the formatter like this:

```
function getFormattedValue(type: string): string {
  const formatter = formatters[type] || formatters.stringUpperCase;
  // ...
}
```

However, I am getting this TypeScript error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ time(value: string): string; date(value: string): string; stringUpperCase(value: string): string; ... }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ time(value: string): string; date(value: string): string; stringUpperCase(value: string): string;... }'.ts(7053)
(property) type: string
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatters` cannot be indexed by `string` because only three *specific* strings exist as property names.

So you need to tell typescript that you expect `type` to be one of the property names of `formatters`. You do this with `keyof`. Any other other string should be a type error.

```
function getFormattedValue(
  type: keyof typeof formatters,
  value: string
): string {
  const formatter = formatters[type];
  return formatter(value)
}
```

Which you would use like so:

```
// Works
getFormattedValue('time', 'a timestamp here')
getFormattedValue('date', 'a date here')
getFormattedValue('stringUpperCase', 'a string here')

// Error as expected
getFormattedValue('asdasd', 'a type error here')
// Argument of type '"asdasd"' is not assignable to parameter of type
//   '"time" | "date" | "stringUpperCase"'.(2345)
```

[Typescript playground with no type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=50&pln=28&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWydkKGAXPFCgJ4CwAUKJLAsulsFBiACoCW+AYkjGxsSmGFxQBzGjSaZ4AMwFCM7GGngBeeAG8a8eBh4gAFADcoEAK4gRGMZICUt+xJ179iVHLQgxFrgBeIMCaOHgEGGYW1gA08Kzs3HxKbHF21g4A3O76cBiWMCjwPn4QgcEAdIqCbMYA5ACyTfAAIkjwAJpdHfAAEr1E2Nh1We4AvjHS1PoJJuZWNsV24hJOSy5u0x6yWCVc-kEhWrj4hFELcXXdHQC0TTctLXVpMBnZW7kg+YXFvvtlhyqKUijWabU63RG730Eym+lEKwAqgAHZG+ADCUB852szhWawRkk2HngeQKRXm1gqGCQKLRMEx2NGW1h1DGU3klhQYEMqHgEi+-BqKmCADVoiZ3BhyGiSABrEDkJDyAwykDKhTA1RoSZbSmLQlSagE5ZE3RbHaa4WqULVZTagDa0rRAF14AAfd1W+2+NAVQ10jFYkDQ0lfcnetiqHEgBw0dnUGgAeiT8AA6gI5WgaAKMEKfcBxQt6oZ8M94HUoAYjJgoNhkfAABa+EAjHOCrViiX1WblyvxNgIZtwNvUXP5qNd4t1AOooM+PtVw1Nluj5OpgCiMBgAlI6hAAA80Tzgu2853C93K2hWDfF6q0fBfDuYCuR3HqCn4ABBGASSynFgGrOggdQAERYrewBgXU8BcOoKBIFgWJoFwEgoFAABGEAIDS8DIrAdZfL48DAWq64eOBpYgGBHrwGBsy0V6YGzvSjI0XUFTGAATAAzAALAArA4QA)

Comment: I am getting `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)` at `formatter(value)`. Any ideas?

Comment: The code I posted does not display that error, so you must be doing something different. If you edit your question with the code that is showing that error, I can probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Oh! `formatter(value)` can take a range of types (number, string, boolean, objects of various structures, etc.). How to fix it then?

Comment: That complicates things _significantly_. I may not have times to write this up, but this works: https://tsplay.dev/wXkxDW

Answer (score 1):

First, time(value: string) is not a string, so you cannot access your function by typing formatters["time"]. It needs to be `{time: (value: string): string => { //your function }`

Secondly, you need to declare formatters as `{[type: string]: Function}` so typescript knows string can be used to index "formatters", and it knows the type of the resulting value will be a function.

Overall, your code would loook like this:

```
const formatters: {[type: string]: Function} = {
  time: (value: string): string => {
    const serialized = moment(value, dateTimeFormat, true);
    return serialized.format('MMM Do YYYY HH:mm');
  },

  date: (value: string): string  => {
    const serialized = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
    return serialized.format('MMM Do YYYY');
  },

  stringUpperCase: (value: string): string =>  {
    return value.toUpperCase();
  },

  // ...
}

function getFormattedValue(type: string): string {
  const formatter = formatters[type] || formatters.stringUpperCase;
  // ...
}
```